# UICollectionView custom layout with different item sizes

Tags: ios, objective-c, collections, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I need to create custom layout like this on the images

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAgfl.png]

Is it possible to do with that method only

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Or I need more complex things here?

Comment: have you tried it before posting your question?

Comment: no, I want to get response from someone experienced in it

Comment: do you want this layout be repeated like, if you consider this layout as 1 set,  will there be more than 1 set? Or do you consider random layout?

Comment: if you want this set to be repeated you can use in collection view cell

Comment: yes I want to repeat it. What should I use to achieve it ?

Comment: You can use two different CollectionViewCells for this and use UIButtons instead of UIImageViews so you have to use target selectors and not didSelectItemAtIndexPath

Comment: @Deepakraj Murugesan, can you describe more about it please ?

Comment: @MatDemon : Any Solution for above design?